# How to display all rake taks that are up-to-date or pending?

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task

I have a rakefile with several tasks and some of them take a lot of time (hours or days).  I usually run some tasks, and left the rest to be executed in another day.  How can I list the status of all the tasks?  I am imaging something like `rake --status` that shows the pending and up-to-date tasks?  I do not want to write a separate to-do list to record the status of tasks.  Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Rake is the Ruby version of Makefile. So it nothing more than a simple Ruby script that executes when asked to. You will need to keep track of which tasks where run and which ones weren't. A better approach would be to keep track of the state of the application/data and then execute the required task depending on your business logic

Comment: So, you propose, for instance, creating a database table associating each task to its status, and after each task execution update the status of the task? This implies that there is no off-the-shell solution for this?

Comment: It could help if we put tasks before and after each task execution. This is explained in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707940/rake-before-task-hook. Also, an extension for these hooks is described here: https://github.com/guillermo/rake-hooks.

Comment: I was researching about how to solve this issue and I found two alternative solutions. 1) If I access the instance of the class `Application` that is created when running rake then I can access all tasks using the attribute `tasks`.  For each task I can use the method `needed?` to check the task status. 2) Create a class `MyTask` that inherits from `Task` but also records the status of the task in a database, to be queried. Also, redefine the method `needed?` to query the database.

Comment: Looks like `sidekiq` and `sidekiq-scheduler` or `sidekiq-cron` fit your needs. If you move your code from rake tasks to sidekiq jobs, you can track their current state. There is a web UI also https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring

Comment: Thanks, I think that the solution I posted below answer my problem. However, I will check `sidekiq` to see if it fits my needs.

Answer (score 1):

I can run the `Rakefile` as any other ruby script.  Then I can access the tasks by using the following code:

```ruby
Rake.application.tasks.each do |tsk|
   puts "#{tsk.name}: #{tsk.needed?}"
end
```

This shows the status of each task.

Also, the class `Task` can be extended to record the status of tasks in a database, and to provide more information about the execution of tasks.

Comment: Your tasks might be run from different processes concurrently (it becomes even more likely in cases like yours - when the task execution takes many hours) - in this case, this solution won't work reliably (Rake::Application will know nothing about its "twins" running in parallel). I'd say if you need precise control you need an external (for Ruby process) mechanism (db/redis/you name it...)